# Application of Kirchoff's junction rule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current

Ok so from my understanding of the junction rule, the current of the 4ohm resistor should be equal to the sum of the currents of the 3ohm and 6ohm resistors. However, the answer key claims that the current of the 6ohm is the sum of the currents of the 4ohm and 3 ohm resistors instead. why is this so?

[image]

Comment: This hinges on the choice of reference direction for each current.  Equation (1) holds if, for example, $I_4$ is positive if left-to-right, $I_3$ is is positive if right-to-left, and $I_6$ is positive if top-to-bottom.  However if, for example, one chooses the reference direction for $I_3$ to be left-to-right, then $I_6 = I_4 - I_3$ or, as you propose, $I_4 = I_3 + I_6$.  In other words, the first step is *to draw* the reference directions for the 3 currents in question and *then* apply the junction rule.

Comment: that's weird, cuz the way they did in the textbook exambles was, say for example the battery on the right side had a lower voltage, then my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Note that the two Kirchhoff's  laws are more commonly called Kirchhoff current law (frequently abbreviated as KCL) and Kirchhoff voltage law (frequently abbreviated as KVL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you set up your equations you should on the circuit diagram label each of the currents and indicate a direction.

Below there are four possible sets of labels.

[image]

Given below are the values of the current that you should have found by applying Kirchhoff's voltage law correctly.

You will see that each of the solutions for the currents are consistent with one another.

Comment: i see it now, my error was forgetting to make the current of the 3ohm resistor "negative" so when I add the currents I should get the same magnitude for the 4ohm. Many thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE- You didn't mention the direction of current flow.**

According to your book, the current in 4 $\Omega$ and 6 $\Omega$ are flowing towards each other,and thus the current in 6 $\Omega$ is the sum of the currents in 4 $\Omega$ and 3 $\Omega$ resistors.

However, if the current in 3 $\Omega$ is flowing towards left and the current in 6 $\Omega$ is flowing upwards, then you are right.

Please also check the direction of current.